# When adding a new object to the list all the objects already added previously are overwritten

Tags: c#, .net, list, overwrite

This is the list that must reference the open classes.

```
readonly List<object> openedClasses = new List<object>();
```

Here is where I create classes and add the list.

```
var employees = myWs.ReturnListEmployee(guid);
foreach (Api.EmployeeData employee in employees)
{
     openedClasses.Add(new MyClass(pendingSchedules[0], employee));
}
```

My class and its constructor:

```
class MyClass
{
    public Schedule schedule;

    public MyClass(Schedule schedule, Api.EmployeeData employee)
    {
        // the "schedule.EmployeeData" it is constantly changed
        this.schedule = schedule;
        this.schedule.EmployeeData = employee;
    }
}
```

My problem is: Every foreach loop all values previously added to the list are overwritten by the most recently added class.

I've tried all the solutions I found on the internet and made the checks, the class is not static and I removed each static method and static field that was called on it (just to make sure), the list I have created with and without the readonly as list of "object" and as a list of "MyClass".

With:

```
openedClasses.Add(new MyClass(pendingSchedules[0], employee));
```

And with:

```
var myClass = new MyClass(pendingSchedules[0], employee);
openedClasses.Add(myClass);
```

Comment: All `MyClass` instances are referencing the same `Schedule` object, so each time someone sets its `EmployeeData` property, all the other instances are affected too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are looping and calling:

```
new MyClass(pendingSchedules[0], employee)
```

Passing the same object `pendingSchedules[0]` around. In the constructor you are doing this:

```
this.schedule.EmployeeData = employee;
```

where `this.schedule` is the same object reference `pendingSchedules[0]`

And you are changing it's employee each time **but the reference stays the same**

You may just want to create a `Clone` method on `Schedule` so that you create a new reference each time from the same reference and put the employee on that:

```
class Schedule
{
    public Schedule Clone()
    {
        return new Schedule
        {
             ValueType1 = this.ValueType1
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: the idea of clone is to break the references, so make sure that any objects you wish to assign to the new `Schedule` reference are broken in a similar fashion. This is why I say `ValueType`, because there aren't references associated with them. So `string`, `int`, `long` etc can just be copied like above.*

Now you can do this:

```
public MyClass(Schedule schedule, Api.EmployeeData employee)
{
    this.schedule = schedule.Clone();
    this.schedule.EmployeeData = employee;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was working all day and it could not see that my mistake. Thank you! The problem was solved. You just saved my day.